# How to prove the coercivity of a bilinear?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be an open connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. the bilinear and continuous form $a : H^1(\Omega) \times H^1(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by
\begin{equation}\label{eq:bilinear}
    a(u,v) = \int_{\Omega} (k \nabla u) \cdot \nabla v \,\mathrm{dx} \quad \forall (u, v) \in \left[H^1(\Omega)\right]^2, 
\end{equation}
where $k\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

Show that $a(u,v)$ is coercive on $H^1_0(\Omega)$ ?

I intend using the *Poincaré's Inequality*, but still get stuck with it.

Comment: Is $k$ real-valued or vector-valued? Do you have boundary conditions on $\Omega$? You typically would need to know that $u$ and $v$ vanish on $\partial\Omega$ to use Poincaré's inequality.

Comment: Pardon me; yes $k$ is real-valued in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ and here the problem I consider have $u = g$ and $v = g$ on $\partial \Omega$. More over $\partial\Omega$ is Lipschitz-continous.

Comment: Are you sure that the bilinear form is defined on $H^1(\Omega)$ and not $H^1_0(\Omega)$? Indeed, it is NOT coercive on the former, because $a(u,u) = 0$ if $u$ is a non-zero constant function.

Comment: Oh I have a mistake here, yes the bilinear is defined on $H^1_0(\Omega)$ as you said.

Comment: Also, you probably have some assumption on $k$. Otherwise, if $k \equiv 0$ on some subset of $\omega \subset \Omega$, you could have $a(u,u) = 0$ for a non-zero $u$ compactly supported in $\omega$.

Comment: Ah yes yes, in my case, $k>0$.

Comment: You probably have an even stronger assumption no? Maybe there exists a $k_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $k(x) \geq k_0 > 0$ on $\Omega$? There are situations where one can handle $k$ vanishing punctually within $\Omega$, but these are very tough inequalities.

Comment: Hmm how about $k(x) = \tilde{k}x$, with $\tilde{k} \in [1,100]$, for instance ?

Comment: What is $\bar{k} x$ for an $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$? Does it vanish at $x=0$?

Comment: $\tilde{k}x$ vanish at $x = 0$, I suppose. But if it not the case, could you tell me what should I do next ?

Comment: Well, if $k(x) \geq k_0 > 0$ on $\Omega$, then $a(u,u) = \int_\Omega k(x) (\nabla u)^2 \geq k_0 \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2$, so the coercivity is just the Poincaré inequality.

Comment: Wow, what a sensational math ! Thank you so much.